# User permission check throws error, but I don't know why

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying for days to find an answer with no luck. I cannot get this to work, so I have to ask it here.

How do I use `@commands.has_permissions`? I've tried a few things.

Here is my code.

```py
@client.command(name="role")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def addrole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"I gave {user.name} the role {role.name}")
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
Ignoring exception in command role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/unkno/Desktop/Code_Tests/Python/discord_bot/bot2.py", line 17, in addrole
    await user.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles        
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\unkno\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your bot dosn't have the `add_roles` permission so you have an error.

Comment: @Mr_Spaar This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the exception is because the bot is missing the `Manage Roles` permission.

You have set it here:

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
```

To fix this simply give your bot the permissions. You can also handle the exception by adding this to your code:

```
@addrole.error
async def addrole_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.ErrorNameHere):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to execute this command!")
```

You will just have to replace `ErrorNameHere` with the name of your error.